# used colons for url htaccess http://localhost/1:1

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, localhost, url

I have a problem with the colons used in url

this my url

http://localhost/1:1

this my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*):(.*) index.php/$1:$2
```

this error show Forbidden You don't have permission to access /1:1 on this server.

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Check the Apache error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here...

1. In a per-directory `.htaccess` context, the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* never starts with a slash, so the regex `^/(.*):(.*)` will never match and the directive does nothing. So, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* would need to be `^(.*):(.*)` - no slash prefix.

   - However, this regex is very *general* and is most probably matching too much. If you are expecting a request of the form `/1:1`, ie. `/<number>:<number>` then use a more specific regex, eg. `^\d+:\d+$`
2. Since you are getting a 403 Forbidden (as opposed to a 404 Not Found) I assume you are on a Windows server. The "problem" here is that `:` (colons) are not valid  characters in Windows filenames. This is an issue with `.htaccess` because the request is mapped to the filesystem before `.htaccess` (and mod_rewrite) is processed - at which point the 403 is triggered. You would need to rewrite the request in the main server config (or VirtualHost container) instead - which occurs *before* the request is mapped to the filesystem.

So, what you are trying to do... rewrite the request that contains a colon, using `.htaccess` on a Windows server is not possible. You can do this on Linux (that permits colons in filenames) OR in the main server config (*server* or *virtualhost* context) on Windows, but **not in `.htaccess`**.

When using mod_rewrite in a *server* (or *virtualhost*) context (as opposed to `.htaccess`) you *do* need the slash prefix (on both the *pattern* and *substitution* strings). For example:

```
# In a "server" (or "virtualhost") context,
#   not ".htaccess" (or "<Directory>" section in the server config)

RewriteEngine On

# Internally rewrite "/1:1" to path-info on "index.php"
RewriteRule ^/\d+:\d+$ /index.php$0 [L]
```

The `$0` backreference contains the entire URL-path that is captured by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. This includes the slash prefix (when used in a *server* context), which is why the slash delimiter is omitted in the *substitution* string.

---

**UPDATE:**

> I made the changes, please look at my question again and see, I entered it correctly
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   ServerName localhost
>   ServerAlias localhost
>   DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
>   <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
>     Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
>         AllowOverride all
>         Order Allow,Deny
>         Allow from all
>   </Directory>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

You don't seem to have made any changes; at least not in the right section? As mentioned above, these directives need to be added directly to the `<VirtualHost>` container (that you have posted). They cannot be added to the `.htaccess` file on a Windows OS - they simply won't do anything and you'll get the 403 Forbidden response as stated.

The above should be written like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"

  # Enable the rewrite engine in a virtualhost context
  RewriteEngine On

  # Internally rewrite "/1:1" to path-info on "index.php"
  RewriteRule ^/\d+:\d+$ /index.php$0 [L]

  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options -Indexes -Includes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You will need to restart Apache for these changes to take effect. (Unlike `.htaccess` files that are interpreted at runtime.)

However, what other directives do you have in `.htaccess` and how are your other URLs being routed? You posted the following directive in comments:

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

This routes the URL quite differently from what you are requesting in your question. In your question you are passing the URL-path as additional path-info to `index.php`. However, in this directive you are passing the URL as part of the query string? How do these relate? Why are they different? You obviously need to pass the URL in the way your "MVC application" is expecting.

Comment: Thank you very much for posting and commenting on this guide for me, but this solution did not work either. Yes, I want this instruction for use in Vamp Server. On a Linux virtual host, if possible, I will try it once. Try

Comment: Or rather, what instructions can I get from the colons in the parameters? Do you have a solution? this my error (Apache/2.4.37 (Win64) PHP/7.0.33 Server at localhost Port 80)

Comment: The solution (workaround) I posted above should work as written. I've tested this on an Apache/Windows server using a `<VirtualHost>` container in the server config and it is working as intended... to pass the URL-path (`/1:1`) as PATH_INFO to the `/index.php` script (which appears to be what you were trying to do in your question). (This isn't the only way to pass the URL-path. You could pass it as a query string or not pass anything and examine `REQUEST_URI` instead - but this depends on what your script is expecting.)

Comment: @amirshariflou Where exactly are you using these directives? Please add the relevant server directives to your question. Did you restart Apache after changing the server config? "what instructions can I get from the colons in the parameters?" - Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by this? Are you still getting a 403 Forbidden? How is your script (`index.php`) expecting to read the URL-path? "this my error" - I don't see an error?

Comment: @amirshariflou I've updated my answer to remove an additional/unnecessary slash in the _substitution_ string. Although this is really just a "tidy-up", it doesn't actually make any difference to it "working" or not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, but my problem was not solved. Please write the exact code for me to find out what it is. I tried many ways but it did not work, but the trap transfer to the Linux host runs there without the need for code. I do not know why it bothers in the wampserver - I even decided to use another xampp. But I know it has to be corrected with a code in the htaccess file

Comment: See this address I want to do exactly that - http://www.recitequran.com/1:1

Comment: @amirshariflou "Please write the exact code for me" - the code in my answer _is_ the exact code. However, you need to place it in the correct place in your server config (not `.htaccess`) and restart your server. This depends on how you've configured your server. Please add the relevant sections of your server config to your question, with these directives in-place - I can then have a look and check. "I do not know why it bothers in the wampserver" - as stated in my answer, this is a limitation of Windows OS, not Apache.

Comment: @amirshariflou " I know it has to be corrected with a code in the htaccess file" - No. As I stated in my answer, you cannot use `.htaccess` for this (on Windows). You need to place these directives in the main server config (or `<VirtualHost>` container).

Comment: @amirshariflou What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file? How are other URLs being routed?

Comment: My routing is because I work with mvc php, and I work according to the standard, but the point here is what should happen in the htaccess file that when you enter the address, the wamp server does not make an error and returns the values 1: 1 as a parameter
Try it on your system once, it's very important that it does

Comment: Error
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /1:1 on this server.
Apache/2.4.37 (Win64) PHP/7.0.33 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Do you have access to the Apache server config? The `<VirtualHost>` container that _defines_ your site? Please edit your question to include this information. "the wamp server **does not** make an error" / "Error Forbidden You don't have permission to access"?! On which server are you getting the "Forbidden" response?

Comment: I made the changes, please look at my question again and see, I entered it correctly

Comment: @amirshariflou I've updated my answer. However, we need to also see the contents of your `.htaccess` file as this might be conflicting and causing additional problems.